# jQuery bind mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, data-binding, click

I need to pass a variable inside a "bind mouse wheel" function and trigger that function when a user clicks on a link.

I just don't know how to do this as I can't put a bind inside an event handler. It just doesn't work.

This is how I tried:

```
$('.link').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   var nbr=$(this).data('article_nbr');

   $("#overlay").bind("mousewheel", function (event,delta,nbr) 
   {
        ...
        scrollTop = $("#article"+nbr).scrollTop();
        scrollTopNew = scrollTop - (delta * 30);
        ...
   }
});
```

I can imagine this is totally wrong but I just can't figure out the proper way to get what I need.

So far I only am able to use bind when the document is ready, but here it should be fired according to some events or event results .

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the effect you want to achieve. From what you've posted  I can't see how this is supposed to perform.

Comment: Ok: I'm displaying articles (one by one) on an overlay without any page refresh on a website that has no overflow. So I need to create my own scroll system on the overlay taking into account a height calculated according to the length of the current article. So, When the user clicks on an link, I get the article number which defines the article div. Now, I try to use this data inside the bind, with no success as 1) I don't know how to fire the bind when an event occur, 2) I don't know how to pass a variable I got from that event to use it inside the "bind". Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define delta and nbr outside as globals, and then you can use it inside.

```
var delta = 10;
var nbr = 'some_value';

$('.link').click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   var nbr=$(this).data('article_nbr');

   $("#overlay").bind("mousewheel", function (event,delta,nbr) 
   {
        ...
        scrollTop = $("#article"+article_nbr).scrollTop();
        scrollTopNew = scrollTop - (delta * 30);
        ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly What I needed. I always thought that, as long as I pass a variable as a parameter through a function, I was just fine. Didn't think of making it global as I believed it wouldn't make any difference. Obviously, it does. It's clear I didn't figure it all out but I will eventually. Thank you.

Comment: WAAAAAAAAT why would you declare as global?

Comment: I got this *[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive*

Answer (score 1):

If i got what you wanted to do, scroll() will do the job

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

```
$("#overlay").scroll(function(){
    // scroll happened ! 
});
```

Comment: The issue remains the same as I can't put this inside an click handler

Comment: "1) I don't know how to fire the bind when an event occur,"
Does scroll answer?

" 2) I don't know how to pass a variable I got from that event to use it inside the "bind". Thank you for your help"
use global variable as @Polakete mentioned

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks